# How to delete the rows Dynamically based on based on ID and Status ="Removed" in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark

Here I have some sample dataset and How to delete the ID's dynamically (no hardcoded values) based on (Column) Status = "Removed".

Sample Dataset:

```
ID  Status       Date      Amount
1   New         01/05/20    20
1   Assigned    02/05/20    30
1   In-Progress 02/05/20    50
2   New         02/05/20    30
2   Removed     03/05/20    20
3   In-Progress 09/05/20    50
3   Removed     09/05/20    20
4   New         10/05/20    20
4   Assigned    10/05/20    30
```

**Expecting Result:-**

```
ID  Status       Date      Amount
1   New         01/05/20    20
1   Assigned    02/05/20    30
1   In-Progress 02/05/20    50
4   New         10/05/20    20
4   Assigned    10/05/20    30
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either **`filter`**, **`not like/rlike`** to `filter out` records from the dataframe that have `status` = `removed`.

```
import org.apche.spark.sql.functions._

//assuming df is the dataframe
//using filter or where clause, trim to remove white spaces lower to convert to lower
val df1=df.filter(lower(trim(col("status"))) !== "removed")

//or by filtering status Removed filter won't match if you have mixed case
val df1=df.filter(col("status") !== "Removed")

//using not like
val df1=df.filter(!lower(col("status")).like("removed"))

//using not rlike
val df1=df.filter(!col("status").rlike(".*(?i)removed.*"))
```

Now **df1** dataframe will have the required records in it.

---

**`UPDATE:`**

**`From Spark2.4:`**

We can use **join** or **window** clause for this case.

```
val df=Seq((1,"New","01/05/20","20"),(1,"Assigned","02/05/20","30"),(1,"In-Progress","02/05/20","50"),(2,"New","02/05/20","30"),(2,"Removed","03/05/20","20"),(3,"In-Progress","09/05/20","50"),(3,"Removed","09/05/20","20"),(4,"New","10/05/20","20"),(4,"Assigned","10/05/20","30")).toDF("ID","Status","Date","Amount")

import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._

val df1=df.
groupBy("id").
agg(collect_list(lower(col("Status"))).alias("status_arr"))

//using array_contains function
df.alias("t1").join(df1.alias("t2"),Seq("id"),"inner").
filter(!array_contains(col("status_arr"),"removed")).
drop("status_arr").show()

//without join using window clause
val w=Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy("Status").rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing)
df.withColumn("status_arr",collect_list(lower(col("status"))).over(w)).
filter(!array_contains(col("status_arr"),"removed")).
drop("status_arr").
show()

//+---+-----------+--------+------+
//| ID|     Status|    Date|Amount|
//+---+-----------+--------+------+
//|  1|        New|01/05/20|    20|
//|  1|   Assigned|02/05/20|    30|
//|  1|In-Progress|02/05/20|    50|
//|  4|        New|10/05/20|    20|
//|  4|   Assigned|10/05/20|    30|
//+---+-----------+--------+------+
```

**`For Spark < 2.4:`**

```
val df1=df.groupBy("id").agg(concat_ws("",collect_list(lower(col("Status")))).alias("status_arr"))

df.alias("t1").join(df1.alias("t2"),Seq("id"),"inner").
filter(!col("status_arr").contains("removed")).
drop(col("status_arr")).
show()

//Using window functions
df.withColumn("status_arr",concat_ws("",collect_list(lower(col("status"))).over(w))).
filter(!col("status_arr").contains("removed")).
drop(col("status_arr")).
show(false)
//+---+-----------+--------+------+
//| ID|     Status|    Date|Amount|
//+---+-----------+--------+------+
//|  1|        New|01/05/20|    20|
//|  1|   Assigned|02/05/20|    30|
//|  1|In-Progress|02/05/20|    50|
//|  4|        New|10/05/20|    20|
//|  4|   Assigned|10/05/20|    30|
//+---+-----------+--------+------+
```

Comment: Not only that particular "Removed" rows, should delete the entire related ID. Please see expecting result

Comment: @NarasimhaL, which version of Spark are you working on?

Comment: Shu, I'm very new to Scala, I dont know anything, as in team suggested I'm just using Databricks_Cluster

Comment: Shu,
I know the below code is completely wrong,
Case studies:-
First needs to define the partition by ID and use the Rownum and Status = “Removed”
where rownum ≠ status(“Removed”)

import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._
var w = Window.partitionBy("id") and (col("status") === "Removed"

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val df1 = df.withColumn("row",row_number.over(w)).where(col("row") === 1 and (col("status") === "Removed")).drop(col("row"))
df1.show()

Comment: Sorry, unable to convey my explanation, due to limit of characters

Comment: If it is possible, can brief me about the code, how it works, could great help: narasimhamoorthy.laddagiri@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `res0` is your dataset, you could do:

```
import spark.implicits._
val x = res0.where($"Status" !== "Removed")
x.show()
```

This will remove the rows with Status as removed, but wont give what you want to achieve based on what you have posted above.

Comment: Not only that perticular "Removed" rows, should delete the entire related ID